# Как вставить символы переноса в строку через равные промежутки?

Tags: c#, .net, строки

Необходимо вставить символы переноса в строку через равное количество символов N.

**Пример входных параметров:**

```
string source = "Hello world!";
int n = 3;
```

**Результат:**

```
string result = @"Hel
lo 
wor
ld!"
```

Comment: Предложите свой вариант решения, и если там будут ошибки -  Вам подскажут. Без Вашего варианта решения здесь никто Вам помогать не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
var s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
int n = 20;
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
{
    sb.Append(s[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % n == 0) sb.Append('\n');
}
var r = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это оно! :))